# Gradient of a function defined on moving curves

Tags: differential-geometry, differential

My question could be summarized as follows: how to differentiate in time a function defined on moving curves, in the following sense.

Let $h(t,\cdot): \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ smooth and let $u(t,\cdot):  G_t \to \mathbb R$ smooth for each $t$, where $G_t = \text{Graph}(h(t,\cdot))$.

Thus $u$ is a family of functions defined on moving graphs. Now let $$w(t,x) = u(t, (x,h(t,x)) )$$
defined on the fixed $\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R$. Since the graphs move smoothly and the $u$ are smooth on each graph, it is tempting to give a meaning to $\partial_t w$.

Formally, one should have
$$\partial_t w(t,x) = \partial_t u(t,(x,h(t,x))) + (\nabla_{G_t} u) (t,(x,h(t,x))) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \partial_t h(t,x) \end{pmatrix}$$

But of course, as the $u(t,\cdot)$ are not defined on the same sets, the chain rule and specifically the second term doesn't make sense directly here. Two possible ideas, by extending $u$ in neighborhoods of the graphs are:

1. At each time extend $u$ by $\bar u$ constantly along the normals to $G_t$ in a small tubular neighbourhood. One can then compute this second term and it yields
   $$\nabla_{G_t} u(t,(x,h(t,x))) \cdot P_{TG_t(x)} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \partial_t h(t,x) \end{pmatrix}$$
   where $\nabla_{G_t}$ is the tangential gradient on $G_t$ and $P_{TG_t(x)}$ is the projection onto the tangent space of the graph at $(t,x)$.
2. Extend $u$ by $\tilde u$ constantly along vertical lines in a small neighborhood of $G_t$. But then, clearly the second term is $0$.

Is there any natural idea on how to compute that quantity ? The normal extension seems to make more sense, but I don't understand why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the problem is that your assumptions don't guarantee that $\partial_t w(t,x)$ even exists and so you can't expect some sort of a chain rule to give you the partial derivative.

In your situation, you have a family $u_t \colon G_t \rightarrow M$ of smooth functions defined on a time-dependent domain. In order for the statement "$u_t$ is smooth" to make sense, the domains $G_t$ should be smooth manifolds. Now, if you want to differentiate $u_t$ in the $t$-direction, you want two things:

1. The manifolds $G_t$ should vary smoothly with $t$. To make sense of this statement, one usually takes $G_t$ to be submanifolds of some ambient space $X$ and which can be described as the images $\sigma_t \colon G \rightarrow X$ of a **fixed** manifold $G$ under a time-dependent parametrization $\sigma_t$. Then $G_t = \sigma_t(G)$ and the statement that $G_t$ vary smoothly (inside $X$) is translated to the fact that the the map $\sigma \colon I \times G \rightarrow X$ is a smooth map (where $\sigma(t,p) = \sigma_t(p)$).
2. The functions $u_t$ should vary smoothly with $t$ as the domain $G_t$ varies smoothly. Since the domains $G_t$ are changing inside $X$, to make sure that $u_t$ varies smoothly in the $t$ direction, the easiest thing to do is to consider a smooth time-dependent map $u \colon I \times X \rightarrow M$ where each $u_t \colon X \rightarrow M$ is defined **on the whole** of the ambient space $X$. This makes sure that as $G_t$ changes inside $X$, $u_t|_{G_t}$ change smoothly along $G_t$.

Under the setting above, you are have a map $\Phi(t,p) = u(t, \sigma(t,p)) \colon I \times G \rightarrow M$ which is guaranteed to be smooth and so $\partial_t \Phi$ makes sense and can be calculated using the regular chain rule.

---

In your case, $G_t$ are smooth one-dimensional curves in $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ which you describe as graphs and so you have a smooth map $\sigma \colon I \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\sigma(t,x) = (x, h(t,x))$. For a fixed $t$, the map $\sigma_t$ parametrizes a single curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and since $h$ is smooth, the map $\sigma$ is also smooth. This handles part $(1)$. However, if all you know is that each $u_t \colon G_t \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function for a fixed $t$ then there's no reason that the composition $u(t,(x,h(t,x)))$ will be differentiable in the $t$-direction.

For example, let $\varphi \colon I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be some arbitrary function and set $h(t,x) := t$ and $u_t(x, t) = x \cdot \varphi(t)$. In this case, the one-dimensional curves $G_t = \operatorname{Graph}(h_t)$ are just the lines $ \{ (x, t) \, | \, x \in \mathbb{R} \}$. The graphs $G_t$ vary smoothly with $t$ and each $u_t \colon G_t \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is definitely a smooth map but the composition $u(t,(x,h(t,x)) = x\varphi(t)$ won't be differentiable in the $t$-direction if $\varphi$ isn't differentiable.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I should also assume that $u$ is smooth in $t$, but since the domains are moving, it is not something I can just "ask like that". 
Thus my ideas of extensions and assuming that they are smooth too (which I forgot to mention). 
If my "normal extension" happens to be smooth, then I can compute $\partial_t w$ as I did by taking $\bar u$ instead of $u$ where it appears. This is pretty much what you proposed, but I define my ext. on some kind of tubular neighborhood instead of the whole X.

The fact is that these are really defined on graphs and they don't have natural extensions.

Comment: The fact is that different extensions of $u(t,\cdot)$ to the whole space or at least to a neighborhood of $G_t$ give different results when using the chain rule. A normal extension in a normal tubular neighborhood gives something quite natural and we can expect, involving the tangential gradient and projections, but some others, for instance the vertical one, yield meaningless results.

I was wondering if there was any natural way of chosing this extension.

Comment: You can choose various extension schemes but they won't always agree with the usual notion of the derivative of $u(t,(x,h(t,x)))$ if it happens to be differentiable so I'm not sure how useful is that. The normal extension will agree with the regular derivative if the variation field of the curves is normal, the vertical extension will agree with the regular derivative if the variation field of the curves is vertical, etc.

Comment: I mean, you can't know a priori what is the relation of the normal extension of $\hat{u_t}|_{G_{t+h}}$ of $u_t$ to $u_{t+h}$ where $h$ is small which is the what is relevant for the regular derivative of $u(t,(x,h(t,x)))$. This depends on how $G_t$ and $u_t$ varies.

Comment: Oh yes, I get it, thanks. This actually depends on the velocity field of the surfaces, of course.

Comment: We can summarize this as follows: assume the graphs $G_t$ evolve by a velocity field $V_t$. If at each time $u$ can be extented in a neighborhood of $G_t$ constantly along $V_t$ and if the resulting extensions are smooth (in space and time), then $w$ is smooth and can be computed classicaly using this extension. This is a _sufficient_ condition for smoothness of $w$.

But this might just be, as you said, "the easiest thing to do". Now I wonder about _necessary_ conditions. The condition you provided seems heuristically necessary as we want to be able to compare $u(t,p)$ and $u(t+h,p)$.